# Insert records in MySql using jdbc but without eclipse

Tags: java

****i phase error like below**
i am writing this code in *notpade++*
how can i build from dose
i don't find out mistake, it is compile success fully but when i try to run it means with this command java JDBCExample it will give an error.

```
    import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet.*;
import java.sql.SQLException.*;

public class JDBCExample
{
//We Declared final variable for jdbc odbc drivers
static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost//student";
    //We Declared Database Credentials
    static final String USERNAME="root";
    static final String PASSWORD="matix";
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt=null;
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Connection to be select the database.......");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
System.out.println("Connection to be database successfully.......");
System.out.println("..............................................................");
System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
stmt=conn.createStatement();
String strquery="INSERT INTO studentlogin"+"VALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')";
stmt.executeUpdate(strquery);
System.out.println("Inserted records into the studentlogin table...");
}
catch(SQLException se){
se.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
try{
if(stmt!=null)
conn.close();
}
catch(SQLException se){
se.printStackTrace();
}
try{
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();
}catch(SQLException se){
se.printStackTrace();
}
}
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
}
```

This example is done in Notepad++
and when i compile using

**javac JDBCExample.java**
no error or exception occur

But when i run this example using

***java JDBCExample***

it will give the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:25)
```

Comment: I have no idea what "*build from dose*" should mean. What kind of tool is that "dose" thing? And what is the error you get when you run it?

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting? As currently we can only imagine. One of the suspect I have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the problem I am suspecting:

```
String strquery="INSERT INTO studentlogin"+"VALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')";
```

This query at runtime becomes like this:

```
INSERT INTO studentloginVALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')";
```

Which is not a valid SQL query.

Change it to:

```
String strquery="INSERT INTO studentlogin "+"VALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')";
```

Comment: notepad++ is simply a code editor. you can't do advaced programs like jdbc in notepad++ because it can't load connecting driver using run time method or dsn.

Comment: you can run jdbc java programs in cmd or ide. Then you get output though you compile the program in notepad++ you can't run it.It simply can't load the java connection driver and I can't find blogs that tell how to execute command line arguements in notepad++. It may be possible.I could only run it in cmd and ide.

Comment: The program maybe correct but that is the difference between code editor and ide.

Comment: I am not saying don't use code editor. You remember more when you code in notepad++ and it comes close to writing on paper. you will forget what you do in ide

Comment: You may have to remember a lot when you do programs in code editor

Answer (score 1):

Use preparedStatement to overcome this type concatenation problems also preparedstatement prevent sql injection

```
PreparedStatement pt=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO studentlogin VALUES(?,?,?)");
pt.setInt(1,1);
pt.seString(2,"JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM");
pt.setString(3,"ABC@123");
pt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between table name and `values` like

```
studentlogin"+"VALUES
```

Do change in query:

```
INSERT INTO studentlogin "+"VALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')
```

assign some space  `studentlogin  VALUES` and remove `+` as it is not required like

```
INSERT INTO studentlogin VALUES(1,'JAGDISHVALA@GMAIL.COM','ABC@123')
```

Comment: in our code we have no space between them studentlogin"+"VALUES